# What level of protection should a firewall give?

Tags: firewall

I am still getting my head around securing our small network and I am not sure to what level of protection a firewall should actually give.

Most firewalls have different features and levels but other than a standard firewall being included at the basic level it is not consistent what can be added. Some other features I've seen include are intrusion prevention (IPS) and Anti Virus and Anti-Phishing at the point of coming in to the network.

**What should I look for as a minimum in a security device, or do you know of any resources which could help guide the decision to this answer?**

One of my main gaps of knowledge is, is anti-virus at the firewall level really required when you have end point anti virus such as Windows Defender? (I should just add we will have a Windows 2012 server as a domain controller etc sitting behind the firewall, in case that changes things).

Comment: I removed the request for opinions. Opinion-based answers are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: I'm still voting to close as opinion based.

Comment: [chat] is a better place to discuss answers to this question. Asking people about justification of costs will only lead to opinion based answers.

Comment: For clarification, this isn't some much about cost but ultimately need. If it is not needed then it is another point of failure and another thing to configure.

Comment: @RonTrunk I've changed it significantly to make it not opinion or cost based, please consider removing the hold on it :)

Comment: I think the answer @ronmaupin gave is as good as you're going to get.  We can't tell you how much security you need, only you can answer that.  We can take this to chat, if you'd like.

Comment: @RonTrunk I'll do just that now then, which room is best?

Comment: I can't until tomorrow

Comment: @tim.baker you can always ask in chat and Ron (or anyone) can always answer later. So go ahead and ask in our dedicated [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11177/).

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you connect to the Internet, your firewall logs will show that there are many attempts to break in, and these attempts continue, non-stop, 24x7.

Not everything is about stealing your property, some people are just malicious, and want to bring you down if they can. Some people want to take over your equipment to launch attacks, send spam, or trade child pornography from your equipment. This can have some serious repercussions for you.

What features you get really depends on your needs, and that is something only your company can answer. You need to decide the level of risk you are willing to tolerate, and weigh that against the resources required to get your risk down to that level. For example, if you have a bunch of naive users, the Anti-Spam, Anti-Phishing, and, perhaps, the Anti-Virus features may well be worth the cost. Only your company can decide.